# Origine del termine riccanza

Tags: word-meaning, etymology, neologism

Guardando la tv mi sono imbattuto in questa, diciamo, trasmissione sulla tv satellitare chiamata **riccanza**.

Tralasciando ogni giudizio sul reality, vorrei
sapere se è un neologismo oppure se ha una sua etimologia simile ad altri termini tipo baldanza, tracotanza, ecc.

Comment: Più che neologismo, direi che è un nome studiato apposta dal team di marketing degli ideatori della trasmissione proprio per evocare l'associazione di idee con i termini che hai citato tu (baldanza, tracotanza, abbondanza, ecc)

Comment: Questo vocabolo non si trova nei dizionari. E secondo [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccanza): «La sigla del programma è stata realizzata dal trio milanese "Il Pagante"».

Comment: Lo si potrà trovare tra i marchi registrati , sicuro ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Su questo articolo presente su Huffington Post intitolato *[#Riccanza: l'adorazione del lusso e la fine delle socialdemocrazie](https://www.huffingtonpost.it/carla-falconi/riccanza-ladorazione-del-lusso-e-la-fine-delle-socialdemocrazie_a_23606864/)* ho trovato una definizione interessante di riccanza, termine catalogato come neologismo:

> Tuttavia **la riccanza, neologismo che mischia la ricchezza con
>   l'abbondanza e l'arroganza**, è diventata quasi un genere televisivo,
>   esportato in Francia, in Spagna e in Sudamerica, e copiato anche da
>   alcuni programmi di Sky in cui, con la scusa di far vedere le case più
>   bel mondo e le barche più belle del mondo (senza far mai vedere i
>   proprietari) si parla solo di lusso e di milioni. È come se la
>   riccanza fosse diventata una meraviglia da mostrare ai poveri, ovvero
>   ai follower, ovvero ai proletari 2.0 che, dall'altra parte dello
>   schermo, guardano attoniti come se venerassero un miracolo.

Sembra che addirittura [l'emittente televisiva MTV abbia indetto una petizione](http://news.mtv.it/tv-cinema/riccanza-la-petizione-per-far-entrare-la-parola-riccanza-nel-dizionario/) per chiedere all'Accademia della Crusca di inserire il termine nel dizionario, anche se cercando sul sito non vi è traccia di alcun elemento a riguardo.

Comment: Se dicono sul serio e non è una battuta, sono altri che non hanno capito che cos'è oggi la Crusca...